# Initiate and shutdown a instance in Spring Mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have following code

```
public enum MyInstances {    
    INSTANCE;
    private InstanceClass instance;

    private MyInstances(String param){initTitanGraph(param);}

    private void initTitanGraph(String param){
        instance = SomeFactoryClass.open(param);
    }

    public InstanceClass getInstance(){
      return instance;
    }

    public void destroyInstance(){
      //destroy or close all instances of InstanceClass class
    }
}
```

Now I want to call

```
 MyInstances.INSTANCE.getInstance();
```

to get the `instance`.

and

```
 MyInstances.INSTANCE.destroyInstance();
```

to destroy `instance`.

I am using spring mvc. How can I implement the same class using spring mvc injection such that on application shutdown `destroyInstance` should be called and I can also use `getinstance()` to get `instance` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

there is no destroy method unless you define it. This doesn't do anything. The actual INSTANCE is still in memory whatever you do, as a singleton.

You are applying th esingleton pattern, just about, to an Enum.

Enums are hardwired by jvm to be singletons, without any extras from the programmer.

Application start and stop in spring can be achieved with `@Postconstruct` and  `@Predestory` annotations.

Comment: oh my mistake I meant that close or shutdown all instances like db.I updated my question. I want an equivalent implementation in terms of spring mvc